# Viewing DOM source using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to figure out how I can view the DOM source for the table at following web page, using Chrome Developer Tools:

https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=eqFinResults

I am interested in scraping the entries from the table (i.e. the table with column names **Symbol, Company, .... , XBRL Filename, Status**).

I tried various options, including:

1. View page Source
2. View Frame Source
3. Highlighting a row in the table and selecting **Inspect**
4. Highlighting the entire page (Ctrl+A) and selecting **Inspect**

I would like to be able to see the HTML code corresponding to:

- a particular row in the table
- the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click > **Inspect** works fine for me.

[image: Inspecting the table]

Comment: Yes it works for me too.  The problem is that I was looking under **Sources**, not **Elements**.